# roslaunch command is not running

Tags: roslaunch, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I created the package my_package inside the SRC folder and then i make a launch folder. In launch folder i make a launch file name name.launch then when i run the command

```
roslaunch my_package name.launch
```

when i pressed enter the following error occurred.

```
RLException: [name.launch] is neither a launch file in package [my_package] nor is [my_package] a launch file name
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

I tried starting rosrun in other terminal and then run the command roslaunch but still the same error is showing

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/360178/roslaunch-command-is-not-running/) by [HASSAN ISMAIL](https://answers.ros.org/users/57491/hassan-ismail/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2020-08-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ray_Shim](https://answers.ros.org/users/56592/ray_shim/) on 2020-08-23**:
If you made your code by using cpp or py, you should modify CMake file.

cpp : http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29

py : http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28python%29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to build and then source your workspace before `rosrun` and `roslaunch` will be able to find files inside your packages. Follow these tutorials to understand the basics of how workspaces are created and used in ROS 1:

1. http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/create_a_workspace
2. http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/CreatingPackage
3. http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/using_a_workspace

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2020-08-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MrRivi](https://answers.ros.org/users/56048/mrrivi/) on 2020-08-24**:
When you create a package you can do it with `catkin_create_pkg <package_name> <package_dependencies>` and do it inside the SRC folder. Then go to your catking folder through terminal and use `catkin_make` or `catkin_make_isolated` or `catkin_build` to build the package. Then you should be able to launch your code.

Also make sure to go to your carkin_ws and do `source devel/setup.bash` .

@Geoff answer is very helpful, although tutorials can be difficult sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please navigate to your source directory and execute following commands:

1. catkin_make
2. source devel/setup.bash

---

Originally posted by [WhilteShad0w](https://answers.ros.org/users/58504/whilteshad0w/) with karma: 11 on 2020-08-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1